# Joomla 3 Article Modal form field in custom module

Tags: module, article, joomla3.1

I want to have an article picker in my custom module. A button and a form field like this one in add new article.

Is ist possible?
I tried this in my module xml:

```
                <field name="article_id" type="modal_article" default="" label="Select an article" description="" />
```

But I only get a form input, not a button to choose an article.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to manually add the path to the modal article element.
In the **< fieldset >** element just above the modal_article field type, add the following attribute:

```
 addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_content/models/fields"
```

So your final xml would look something like this:

```
<fieldset name="basic" addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_content/models/fields">
<field name="article_id" type="modal_article" default="" label="Select an article" description="" />
```

Comment: Now I have a link to my article like "index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=17". But is it possible to get the link with the aliases? ...like a menu link /test/mysite.html

Comment: Is SEF enabled on your site?

Comment: I am on Joomla 2.5 and tried to apply the same solution. I was able to add the field but the labels are not correctly translated. I only see: `COM_CONTENT_SELECT_AN_ARTICLE` instead of the correct text string. Any idea what I must change for 2.5?

Comment: once done... how would you grab this and make it a link to the article? via the php file - as mine just links to the article ID - i.e. http://localhost:8888/joomla32/1